# Is it possible to create a dataflow without giving script lines using azure sdk in python?

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-python

Is it possible to create a dataflow without giving script lines using azure sdk in python? if yes please share a sample code creating a dataflow contains source, transformation and sink.

I need following dataflow as output using azure sdk in python.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a dataflow without giving script lines using azure sdk in python?

- No, it is not possible to create a dataflow without specifying the script lines of the dataflow object. The code however wouldn't fail and would create a dataflow.

```
#creating a MappingDataFlow object to use in creating dataflow.
new_mapdf = dt.models.MappingDataFlow(type = 'MappingDataFlow', sources=dataflow.sources,sinks=dataflow.sinks)

new_df = dt.models.DataFlowResource(name='dataflow2', type= 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/dataflows', properties=new_mapdf)
```

- But it throws the error as shown in the below image when you check in UI of this newly created dataflow.

[image]

- There are classes for each of the Data Factory activities, but the classes related to DataFlow are limited. And there are almost no examples of these classes apart from the class definitions for these classes. So, it might not be possible to create or update the dataflow without Script lines being specified.